# Webservice in PHP with SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to get a SOAP web service to run with PHP. But when i am running the file the page shows nothing. I tried to create a client to see if the code runs that way but the function doesn't run. 
Here is my code:

webservice.php

```
function hello(){
    echo("hi");
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri'=>'http://localhost/FutureWB/hello'));
$server->addFunction("hello");
$server->handle();
```

testweb.php

```
try{
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location'=>"http://localhost/FutureWB/functions/webservice.php",
    'uri' => "http://localhost/FutureWB/hello"

));

$result = $client->hello();
echo($result);


}catch(SoapFault $ex){
    $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: check with firebug , what is the error you are getting

Comment: There are no errors given. Just a blank page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry not a great SoapClient user but how about this,

```
function hello(){
    return "hi";
}
```

Comment: Wait sorry. This does indeed fix it. Thanks alot!

Comment: GR8, glad I helped, one of the keys to Soap development seems to be working out how to set up logging on the Client and the Server, else it can threaten you sanity.  I'm fine now, though.